# C: printing %c doesn't work when I put the value in brackets

Tags: c, string, printf

That's my first post here and I tried to be as specific with the title as I could. Sorry for any errors :)

I'm doing my pset for a CS course and I have a problem with printing my value. When I put the value like this: `(%c, p[j] + k%26)` the program prints it. When I put it in the brackets as below it doesn't. And that's an important difference in this case.

Do you have any advice for me? If so please do not write any code as we are not permitted to receive any code from outside. Just let me know if in C the thing I'm doing is just illegal or maybe ask some open question that might help!

**Relevant part of the Code**

```
for (int j = 0, m = strlen(p); j < m; j++)
{
    if (isalpha(p[j]))
    {
        printf("%c", (p[j] + k)%26);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c", p[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this for CS50?

Comment: Characters with ascii values from 0 to 25 are not always printable... And yeah, I suggest you refresh your BODMAS (or whatever you call it)

Comment: There's a [cs50](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: A good first debugging step might've been: `printf("%d\n", 'a');
 printf("%d\n", 'a' + 5%26);
 printf("%d\n", 'a' + (5%26));
 printf("%d\n", ('a' + 5)%26);` That might've somehow eventually led you to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII.

Answer (score 5):

You mean in the *parentheses*.

This:

```
p[j] + k % 26
```

is different than:

```
(p[j] + k) % 26
```

because of the [operator preceding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), where the modulo will be executed before the addition. However, the formula that is enclosed into the parentheses will have the highest preceding, thus will be executed first.

---

As a result in the first case `k % 26` will be executed first, and its result will be added to `p[j]`.

In the second case, `p[j]` will be added to `k`, and that sum will be affected by `% 26`.

As you can see these two things are different, thus explaining the different behavior you experience.

---

And as Eugene mentioned, characters with ascii values from 0 to 25 are not always printable.

Answer (score 2):

When you perform `(p[j]+k)%26`, you get a value between `0-25`. refer the ASCII table these values represent control characters.

---

I am assuming you are coding for some cipher. In that case you just need to subtract 26 from `p[i]+j`. Remember ASCII values for alphabets are not `0-25`

Answer (score 0):

It's expected adding an offset to a character is some character and that is in first case might in range `p[j]` to `p[j]+25` and in second case also

you just try to print something having ascii value 0 to 25 which might be something like non-printable.

But in both cases you may face something non printable.

`%` has higher precedence than `+` so in first case
`p[j] + (k%26)`

In second case
`(p[j] + k)%26`

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different things as the `%` operator has precedence wrt the sum, so it is a matter of math. The code

```
printf("%c", (p[j] + k)%26);
```

always prints a character, but in this case you are applying the modulo operation (`%`) to the final value, resulting in a number from 0 to 25. Note that none of this character are printable (i.e. they are blank spaces or others --- see an ASCII table).

Answer (score 0):

well that because the result will be some numbers from 0 to 25 which btw is unprintable in ascii code so you have to add 65 if the number is uppercase or 97 if the number is lowercase here is [the ascii code table](https://www.ascii-code.com/) to understand more

```
for (int j=0, m = strlen(p); j < m; j++)
if (isalpha(p[i]))
{
  if (isupper(p[i]))
   {
     printf("%c",((text[i] - 65 + k) % 26) + 65);
   }
  else
  {
     printf("%c",((text[i] - 97 + k) % 26) + 97);
  }

}
  else
      printf("%c",text[i]);
```